# How can I use an onScroll event in React to move to another page using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, onscroll

I currently have a hero image component in React, and i'd like to move to a shopping page when the user attempts to scroll down the page, as if they were connected when in reality they aren't. this would make my other navigation a lot easier, while still keeping all components and routes seperate.

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    let history = useHistory();
    history.push('/categories');
    console.log('done');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Hero onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
```

my console.log never gets executed.

Comment: Can't you use nested routes to add `categories` below `Hero` component and just render `categories` component based on condition.

Comment: so there is a component called hero, and its an image while scrolling and going down of the image you need to show a different route which is categories . Is that what you are trying to achieve

Comment: yes, hero is a hero image, that takes up 100% of the viewport height and width, thus there is not a scroll bar by default. I tried changing overflow y to scroll on the element but that didn't work and left me with a scroll bar which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change **onScroll** with **onWheel**

```
<Hero onWheel={this.handleScroll}>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, any other suggestions?